# n:m sql statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need some help with the following sql statement. I have three tables, one stores urls (web), one stores userdata (user) and a relationship between them (web_user, n:m).

```
CREATE TABLE web (
    url_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    url varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE user (
    usr_id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username varchar NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar NOT NULL,
    language varchar
);

CREATE TABLE web_user (
    url_id integer NOT NULL,
    usr_id integer NOT NULL,
    alias varchar NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( url_id, usr_id)
);
```

I want to execute a query to receive all stored urls for a specific user, lets say usr_id 25525. I tried the following, but it did not work properly..

```
sqlite> SELECT web.url_id, web.url 
        FROM web 
        JOIN web_user ON web.url_id = web_user.url_id 
        JOIN user ON user.usr_id = web_user.usr_id 
        WHERE user.usr_id = 25525;
```

Can anyone give me a tip what is wrong here?

Edit:

Here is some sample data from each table:

**web**

```
SELECT url_id, url FROM web;
2|https://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed01
3|https://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed02
4|https://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed03
```

**user**

```
SELECT usr_id, nickname, firstname, lastname, language FROM user;
25525|TestDummy|Jonathan|Snow|DE
```

**web_user**

```
SELECT usr_id, url_id, alias FROM web_user;
25525|2|feed01
25525|3|feed02
25525|4|feed03
```

I am expecting 3 results in format web.url_id, web.url for user 25525. Using the query above I receive 0 results sadly.. I have no idea whats wrong here..!

Comment: Why did it not work properly. How many rows you expecting, and how many you getting. Why not just Doha query to start with between web and web user. You select no columns from user, so no need to join to it. Maybe put user table in [ ], as it may be referring to a reserved word

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query.  How about presenting some data, describing the result you expect, and presenting the actual result obtained?

Comment: I added some more information about the stored data.. Sorry for that!

Comment: No need to join by the way: `select url_id, url from web where url_id in (select url_id from web_user where usr_id = 25525)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! It was sitting right in front of the computer as always.

I was using a prepared statement in my application and mixed up the values of usr_id and url_id, so the usr_id had url_id values and the other way around. I fixed it and now everything is working fine. Thanks everyone for your help!